# High side switch load isn't working as intended per datasheet. The output is always high at 12V

Tags: switching, pulse, high-side

I bought a [high side load switch](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/si1865ddl-1764206.pdf) from Mouser, and per the datasheet, I added 13kohms for R1, connected Pin 1 directly to GND. The input (ON/OFF) at Pin 5 is a 5V pulse with a frequency of 20Hz and the input (Vin) at Pin 4 is 12V DC.

I don't know why but the output remains high at 12Vdc. I would like to see my Vout switching between 12V to 0V since my ON/OFF input is a 5V, 20Hz pulse signal. Not sure what I have done wrong.

[image]

[[image]][]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120115/discussion-on-question-by-sam-high-side-switch-load-isnt-working-as-intended-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my circuit work; I did not have to make any changes to the circuit. After my fourth failure with changes in circuitry, I decreased the solder from 500 degree to 400 degree Celsius, and used tweezer and it worked. I am assuming the erratic behavior of all my failed circuit is either due to me holding the component when soldering or using a high temperature solder iron.

Comment: 400C is way too hot. Even 350C is way too hot. Why do you need anything above 300C? Use a bigger soldering iron tip.

Comment: And 300C is for lead-free solder. You can solder lead-free fairly easily at 280C. If you are using leaded solder you shouldn't need anything higher than 250C.

Comment: Got it. I will make sure to keep it at 300C from now on for lead-free solder. Thanks

Comment: If you don't trust your temp dial or sensor start at the melting point (180C for leaded and 220-240C for lead-free depending on alloy) and just keep turning up the temp until a properly sized large tip touching a joint melts the solder any amount at all within 1-2 seconds. It will be sticky and not flowy. Then go 50-60C above that.